# Override Doctrine Yaml mapping in app/Resources

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, mapping, yaml

I am building a bundle using Doctrine entities and i want to give the possibility to replace the yaml mapping with another one in `app/Resources/config/doctrine`.

Example : i have an entity `Jml\FooBundle\Entity\Stuff` with a base yaml mapping in `Jml/FooBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Stuff.orm.yml`

I'd like the user of my bundle to be able to replace this mapping with either `app/Resources/config/doctrine/Jml.FooBundle.Entity.Stuff.orm.yml`

It seems i need to add a path in the `SymfonyFileLocator`, but i don't know exactly how to do this. I tried to adapt this [documentation post](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/doctrine/mapping_model_classes.html) 
but failed so far.

How could i add the `app/Resources/config/doctrine` in the mappings for the entites in the namespace `Jml\FooBundle\Entity` ?

Comment: You can customize the directories that symfony/doctrine uses for mapping: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think it is possible to mix it with `auto_mapping: true` ?

Comment: Probably not but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

As [Symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html#entities-entity-mapping) says:

> Due to the way Doctrine works, **it is not possible to override entity mapping of a bundle**. However, if a bundle provides a mapped superclass (such as the User entity in the FOSUserBundle) one can override attributes and associations. Learn more about this feature and its limitations in the Doctrine documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should be more clear: i do not really want to override the mapping, but to REPLACE the mapping. ie, i'd like to add a path in the mappings. I think it's not totally like override. Am i wrong ? (just edited my post to be more clear)

Comment: I tried to use the same technique as in this example of mapping override: http://docs.akeneo.com/1.5/cookbook/catalog_structure/overriding_the_orm_product_value.html#id2